# replace values for specific rows more efficiently in pandas / Python

Tags: pandas, loops

I have two data frames, based on a condition that I get from a list (which length is 2 million) I get rows that match that condition, then for those rows I change the values in columns x and y in the first data frame by the values of x and y in the second data frame. Here is my code, but it is very slow and makes my computer freeze. Any idea how I can do this more efficiently ?

```
for ids in List_id:
    a=df1.index[(df1['id'] == ids )==True].values[0]
    b=df2.index[(df2['id'] == ids )==True].values[0]
    df1['x'][a] = df2['x'][b]
    df1['y'][a] = df2['y'][b]
```

thank you

--

Example:

List_id=[1, 11 , 12 , 13]

ids=1

a=df1.index[(df1['id'] == 1 )==True].values[0]

print('a') : 234

b=df2.index[(df2['id'] == 1 )==True].values[0]

print('b') : 789

df1['x'][a] = 0

df2['x'][b] =15

So at the end I want in my data frame 1:

df1['x'][a] = df2['x'][b]

Comment: please share sample input and expected output

Comment: I put a simple example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have repeated id in both dataframe, you can try something like below: 
step-1: filtering df2 
step-2: joining df1 with filtered one 
step-3 replace values in joined df and dropping extra columns.

```
df2_filtered=df2[df2['id'].isin(List_id)]
join_df = df1.setIndex('id').join(df2_filtered.setIndex('id'), rsuffix = "_ignore", how = 'left')
# other columns from df2 will be null, you can use that to get the rows which needs to be updated
```